# Is it possible to restart story missions in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Because in the DLC for Pirates booty one of the missions is to climb a light house and put the compass in it. The only problem is that the quest marker says that I've done the specified objective, but won't update to a new one. The quest I believe is called Let There be light.

Comment: You can't fast travel to the lighthouse from Wurmwater, you have to open the gate

Answer (score 1):

No you can't replay missions already done but you can create a new character and play it again or simply ask a friend who haven't done the mission and host it so you could join him and replay the mission.