# Can I restart the story missions in True Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I started a new game on TVHM and got to where you meet Roland's spy Mordecai. Then I went to test multiplayer and finished the game with the team I was in, it asked me something like "Do you want to skip all the missions you would do" and I didn't understand it was saying so I just said yes to continue.

After that I went back to the menu and chose continue. ( 1 Player )
Suddenly I was at where the team quit and I had no more Story missions available.

Eventually I decided to start over on TVHM with that lvl 50 but it won't let me. When I choose "New Game" It will only let me create a new character.

How do I start another TVHM game from the beginning with my existing level 50 character?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade!  I changed the title to be a little more descriptive, based on my interpretation of your question.  Better titles tend to elicit more views, which in turn brings more opportunities for good answers.  Let me know if the edit is correct.

Comment: Ignore that duplicate vote: IMO [this older question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89679/is-it-possible-to-restart-story-missions-in-borderlands-2) should be closed as a dupe of this, better asked and answered question

Answer (score 12):

You only get one fresh restart of the story missions with TVHM (the same is true of normal mode).

When you played online, your game recorded how many story missions were beaten while you were present.

When you continued in 1-Player, the game asked you if you wanted to skip past the missions that you already completed online, and you said yes, you skipped ahead to the next incomplete story mission (in this case, to the end of the game, as there were none).

Also, choosing New Game only ever creates a new character. TVHM isn't (strictly speaking) a New Game, it is a different game mode that can only be started with a character that has already completed normal mode.